# Spiral towards a point iteratively

Tags: three.js

I tried to move the object using

```
if(Math.abs(ay-y)>0.8)
    {
        cubes[i].position.y += 0.01*(ay-y);
    }
    else
    {
        cubes[i].position.y = (i_posy[i]-miny) + ay+Math.sin(t)*0.8;
    }
```

but that doesn't get the 
[image]

effect I want, red is the point of attraction, black is path to follow, any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/logarithmic-spiral/9913?u=prisoner849) will give you some ideas.